# Android user agent in URLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, user-agent, urlconnection

I'm trying to "fool" Google Finance into thinking I'm a web browser by changing the user agent property in my connection. However, the response I get back still isn't what I should get when I use an actual web browser. I was wondering why this is, and what I need to do in order for it to work? Here is the relevant code (the "site" is https://www.google.co.uk/finance/converter?a=1&from=GBP&to=USD):

```
protected static String readURL(String site) {
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(site).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393");
        conn.connect();
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = bfr.readLine()) != null)
            buff.append(inputLine).append('\n');
        bfr.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ioe) {
        System.err.println("Failed to read from \""+site+"\": "+ioe.getMessage());
    }
    return buff.toString();
}
```

EDIT: I should note that this is in an Android application, not a Java one. It is also not displayed to the user in a WebView or anything, this happens in the background.

Comment: What *do* you get back? Also, I'm not sure why you are trying to load a dynamic form

Comment: In what way is it different from what you expect? My first guess would be that part of the DOM you're expecting is actually constructed by JavaScript at runtime, not part of the HTML, and that may explain the discrepancy.

Comment: I can't post the full HTML here, it'd be too verbose. But it's nothing to do with DOM or JavaScript. My problem is what I get back from the browser and the programmatic querying is vastly different; and that can only be because Google knows I'm not using a "real" web browser. Infact I know this because I've done it before and it worked, but Google must've recently changed their site to detect automated queries.

Answer (score 0):

The webform seems to behave normally without mucking with the user agent.  This retrofit request returns a valid response:

```
D/TAG: currency_converter_result>5 GBP = <span class=bld>6.3645 USD
```

Retrofit request:

```
      final Map<String,String> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();

      fieldMap.put("a","5");
      fieldMap.put("from","GBP");
      fieldMap.put("to","USD");

      RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "");
      final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl("https://www.google.co.uk")
               .build();

         final ConversionService wService = retrofit.create(ConversionService.class);
         Call<ResponseBody> data  = wService.convertCurrency(fieldMap);

         data.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
               String resp = "";

               if ( response.body() != null ) {
                  try {
                     resp = response.body().string();
                     int index = resp.indexOf("currency_converter_result" );
                     int end = resp.indexOf("</span>", index );
                     String result = resp.substring(index, end);
                     Log.d("TAG", result);
                  } catch ( IOException e) {
                  }
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

               Log.e(TAG,"Failure");
            }
         });

   }
```

ConversionService.java

```
public interface ConversionService {

   @GET("/finance/converter")
   Call<ResponseBody> convertCurrency(@QueryMap Map<String,String> queryMap);
}
```

Comment: I would like to be able to do this without using any additional libraries.